Neural network training issues recognizing chess pieces
I need advice regarding my pet project. I'm building a chess piece recognition mechanism, using Python's PyTorch library.
Now I have 2 main issues:

My dataset.
How should I prepare my images?
I have 7 classes: king, knight, pawn, rook, queen and empty.
If I'm using"torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder" - what is the best way to distribute my images into folder?
Does image style play a role, for example, if I have a graphic illustration of a chess piece vs a picture taken from a chessboard of a piece - should they be split into 2 different categories/classes?
Also, what other image characteristics play a role as far as categorizing the images (color, gradients etc)?
* also, does the amount of images in each folder has to be equal?

My training yields an accuracy of 94%. However, my prediction gives out wrong results.
I was wondering if besides the obvious - tweaking augmentation and handling overlift; what else can be done? Does it make sense and is it possible to handle each category/class separately (transforms, layers)?


Here's my code:
1. The training itself is in "neural_net.py":
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from PIL import Image
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        # Layer 1
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(3, 32,3),
                                   nn.ReLU(),
                                   nn.MaxPool2d(3, 2))
        # Layer 2
        self.conv2d_2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, (3,3))
        self.relu_2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool_2 = nn.MaxPool2d(3, 2)
        # Layer 3
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(179776, 32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 7)
    def forward(self, x):
        # Layer 1
        y = self.conv1(x)
        # Layer 2
        y = self.conv2d_2(y)
        y = self.relu_2(y)
        y = self.maxpool_2(y)
        # Layer 3
        y = y.view(y.size(0), -1)
        y = self.fc1(y)
        y = self.fc2(y)
        return y
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, class_names):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap="Blues", xticklabels=class_names, yticklabels=class_names)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
    plt.ylabel('True')
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
    plt.show()
def main():
    print("Main block is running")
    # Early stopping parameters
    early_stopping_patience = 3
    best_val_loss = float('inf')
    epochs_no_improve = 0
    batch_size = 8 #64
    step_size = 7 #10
    epoch_max = 40;
    # Define transformations with various augmentations
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize([224,224]),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    ])
    from_google_drive = False
    #google drive is accesible only on dev mode, not locally
    if from_google_drive:
        from google.colab import drive
        drive.mount('/content/drive')
        # Set the path to your dataset in Google Drive
        train_data_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/dataset/train'
        test_data_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/dataset/test'
    # for local scan
    else:
        train_data_path = '/Users/sabina.livny/Pictures/dataset'
        test_data_path = '/Users/sabina.livny/Pictures/dataset'
    train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=train_data_path, transform=transform)
    test_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=test_data_path, transform=transform)
    print("Class names:", train_data.classes)  # Check that classes are defined
    # DataLoader for GPU
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
    # Device setup
    if torch.backends.mps.is_available():  # For Apple Silicon GPUs (macOS)
        device = torch.device("mps")
    elif torch.cuda.is_available():  # For NVIDIA GPUs on Linux/Windows
        device = torch.device("cuda")
    else:
        device = torch.device("cpu")  # Default to CPU
    # Move the model to the selected device
    net = NeuralNet().to(device)
    loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=step_size, gamma=0.1)  # Adjusted step_size
    manual_train = True  # Set this to True to trigger training
    if manual_train:
        for epoch in range(epoch_max):
            print(f'Training epoch {epoch}....')
            net.train()
            running_loss = 0.0
            for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
                inputs, labels = data
                inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                outputs = net(inputs)
                loss = loss_function(outputs, labels)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                running_loss += loss.item()
            avg_train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
            print(f'Training Loss: {avg_train_loss:.4f}')
            # Validation phase
            net.eval()
            val_loss = 0.0
            with torch.no_grad():
                for data in test_loader:
                    inputs, labels = data
                    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
                    outputs = net(inputs)
                    loss = loss_function(outputs, labels)
                    val_loss += loss.item()
            avg_val_loss = val_loss / len(test_loader)
            print(f'Validation Loss: {avg_val_loss:.4f}')
            # Early stopping check
            if avg_val_loss < best_val_loss:
                best_val_loss = avg_val_loss
                epochs_no_improve = 0
                torch.save(net.state_dict(), 'best_model.pth')
            else:
                epochs_no_improve += 1
            if epochs_no_improve == early_stopping_patience:
                print(f'Early stopping triggered at epoch {epoch}.')
                break
            # Save model every epoch (optional)
            torch.save(net.state_dict(), 'trained_net.pth')
            # Learning rate scheduler step
            scheduler.step()
    else:
        print("Training skipped. Set manual_train to True to start training.")
    # Manual flag for evaluating the model
    evaluate_model = True  # Set to False to skip evaluation
    compute_confusion_matrix = True
    # List of class names
    class_names = train_data.classes
    if evaluate_model:
        net.eval()
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        all_labels = []
        all_predictions = []
        with torch.no_grad():
            for data in test_loader:
                images, labels = data
                images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
                outputs = net(images)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                total += labels.size(0)
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
                if compute_confusion_matrix:
                    all_labels.extend(labels.cpu().numpy())
                    all_predictions.extend(predicted.cpu().numpy())
        accuracy = 100 * correct / total
        print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}%')
        if compute_confusion_matrix:
            # Compute confusion matrix
            cm = confusion_matrix(all_labels, all_predictions)
            plot_confusion_matrix(cm, class_names)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

2. And this is the "scan.py" file where I perform the predictions:
# Make a prediction using the model
def predict(images):
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize([224,224]),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    ])
    predicted_classes = []
    model = NeuralNet()
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load('trained_net.pth'))  # Load the saved weights
    model.eval()  # Set model to evaluation mode
    with torch.no_grad():  # Disable gradient calculation
        for image_path in images:
            img = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
            img = transform(img)
            img = img.unsqueeze(0)
            img = img.to(next(model.parameters()).device)
            output = model(img)  # Forward pass
            _, predicted_class = torch.max(output, 1)  # Get the predicted class
            predicted_classes.append(predicted_class.item())
    return predicted_classes  # Return list of predicted class indices
    def scan_pieces(file):
    # Using the factory to create a piece
    piece = PieceFactory.create_piece("rook")
    piece.file = file  # This will trigger the setter
    squares_images = get_images_cropped(file)
    # You can call this to predict the class based on the processed image
    predicted_classes = predict(squares_images)  # Make the prediction
    # Print the class name
    class_names = ['queen', 'rook', 'bishop', 'knight', 'pawn', 'king', 'empty']
    # Print the predicted classes for all images
    for index, predicted_class in enumerate(predicted_classes):
        # Ensure the predicted_class index is within the range of class_names
        if predicted_class < len(class_names):
            print(f"Predicted Class for square {index + 1}: {class_names[predicted_class]}")
        else:
            print(f"Predicted Class for square {index + 1}: Unknown class (index {predicted_class})")

Basically, I want to train a model to recognize chess pieces so that later on I can use those weights to compare to an uploaded image taken from a screenshot of some chess position, which later on I can position the pieces on the board based on the uploaded image.
Here's my confusion matrix:


Hello, since this question is not about coding but rather about datascience, I think you will have a better chance of getting an answer if you ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/
